# Phonegap with QuaggaJS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap, getusermedia

I want to build apps for android and ios tho scan barcodes with QuaggaJS.
So i have built a website, which works fine in the browsers on ios and android.
It asks for permission for the camera and every thing is fine.

I am new at Phonegap.
When i paste the code to the index.html of the phonegap-project and copy all needed files to the folder and compile with build.phonegap.com there is only a symbol of the camera but no stream.

I have added the "phonegap-plugin-media-stream.git" plugin with

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-media-stream.git" source="git" />
```

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you have error in console and this for that you'r code block and stream don't appear.

If you used a real device you can build a debug version of you'r apk (no key selected with build.phonegap.com), connect you'r android to you'r pc and use [chrome inspecter](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) for see what append.